# Dynamo DB, How do you query everything AND leverage sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I already have an index set up with the second sort key set to what I want (an integer timestamp). The API keeps complaining that I'm not giving it a KeyConditionExpression.  Then if I give it one, it says id must be specified.  I've tried forcing it to just give me everything using id <> null and it STILL won't do it.  Is this even possible??  Maybe its time to get rid of dynamo if it can't do this utterly simple task.

For the love of god, all I'm trying to do is query the entire table AND have it use my sort key.  I would have had this going in SQL hours ago..

Answer (score 7):

First of all, DynamoDB is a NOSQL database, so it's intentionally NOT SQL. Perhaps you shouldn't expect to be able to perform SQL like queries that you are used to, and be frustrated by the fact that these are two completely different types of databases, each with its strengths and weaknesses.

Records in DynamoDB are partitioned using the hash key, and may optionally be sorted within each partition. 
The hash key should be picked so that items are as evenly distributed over partitions as possible. The use of partitions is what makes DynamoDB extremely scalable and fast. But if what you need is to *scan* over all your items and get them in sorted order, then you probably either are using the wrong tool for the job, or you need to sort the items on the client side.

The scan operation will simply go through all partitions, returning all items from each partition. At this point, the items can only be sorted within their respective partition.

As an example, consider a set of data being partitioned into 3 partitions:

```
Partition A                Partition B                Partition B

Sort key                   Sort key                   Sort key
A                          D                          C
C                          E                          K
P                          G                          L
```

As you can see, you can easily query each partition and get the items in it in sorted order. But if you scan, you will probably get items sorted as
[A, C, P, D, E, G, C, K, L], if the sort order is at all deterministic. At this point you would have to sort the items yourself.

A "trick" that is sometimes seen is to use a "dummy" hash key with an equal value for all items, like you mentioned in your own answer. This way you can query for "dummy = 1" and get the items sorted according to the sort key. However, this completely defeats the purpose of the hash key as all items will be put in the same partition, thus not making the table scale at all. But if you find yourself using DynamoDB even though you have a really small dataset, by all means it would work. But again, with a small data set and use-cases like this, you should probably be using another tool such as RDS in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @JHH though. In general I'd say he is correct that you shouldn't need to sort all elements in DynamoDB. I also have a requirement similar to this, as I need to get the top `N` number of elements, which could all be in different partitions.

DynamoDB does have a way of doing this, it just isn't out of the box. I don't think that it's so correct to say you should then need an SQL database, as arguably you'd never use a NoSQL database because you will always have one of these limitations. Also if you only ever use NoSQL for large data-sets then you will always have to rework your application later.

What to do then? Well you do have a few options, and it depends on your use-case, lets' assume that you are at least having sorting within your partitions, this makes it easier. We'll also assume you are looking for the max.

- The simplest way would be if you would get the first value from every partition. And find the max. If you needed say the top 10 values you could still utilise this strategy but would get too complicated.
- Next option is to make use of DynamoDB Streams. Say we want to keep a list of the top 100 elements. These would sit ready and waiting on their own top values partition, sorted and ready for instant retrieval. You would need to maintain this list yourself by checking when items are inserted or updated, that they are greater than the 100th element. If that is the case you would insert the element into the top values partition, and delete the last value. This I think would be the most likely way to approach this problem.

So in NoSQL if there is some sort of query, you would love to do which is oh so easy in SQL, and you cant use your Table/GSI/LSI, then you pretty much need to compute the result manually, and have it ready for consumption.

Now if you weren't going to make use of these top values very often, then you might go with the first method, and scan every partition top values till you had the list you wanted, but depending on how much the values are scattered across partitions this could take many capacity units.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out, you can also add an IndexName to a scan.  That helps.  Furthermore, if you create an index with a sort key, all primary indices MUST be identical for the sort to occur.

Comment: All the IndexName does is return items from the Index rather than the table.