# How can I query DynamoDB with sort and limit for a non sort key parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a simple "scoreboard" using DynamoDB and API Gateway. I can pull straight from Dynamo just fine, but I want to only show the top 10 rows. Basically, API Gateway should only return the top 10 scores. The database uses a shared value for its partitionkey to return everything. I set the sorting key to a timestamp to make sure each row is unique. The other two columns are "nickname" and "score". I'd like to be able to just pull the top 10 rows based on the score column. Any ideas?

This is my mapping template:

```
{
    "TableName": "pacman",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "entire = :v1 AND recordTime > :v2",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('entire')"
        },
        ":v2": {
            "S": "$input.params('recordTime')"
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, it successfully returns all rows in my table.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Answer (score 4):

Without having `score` as a sort key for your table, you'll need to perform full table scans that can start to become costly over time, especially as your database grows. If your data is known to have a consistent schema, [RDS (MySQL, PostgreSQL) alternatives may be the better tool for the job.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882735/10885720)

If you're set on DynamoDB, depending on your access pattern, and if you find yourself consistently performing this action, it might make sense to have another table with `score` as the sort key. You can accomplish this by creating a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) or [Local Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) which automatically sync with your base table. That page has a useful example with scoreboards that closely resembles what you're looking for.

Once you have your second index, or you've changed your sort key to `score`, you can perform a more efficient `query` from your application code with the following constraints:

- Set `ScanIndexForward` parameter to `false`, to perform the search in descending order (highest score first)
- Set `limit` parameter to `10` to stop further querying of DynamoDB after the max number of items is returned

As a query, this would look like the following:

```
QueryParam = {
       TableName: 'pacman',
       IndexName: 'ScoreIndex', // Name of your local/global secondary index
       KeyConditionExpression: "Score = :Score  ", // Shared partition key
       ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":UserId": UserId,
       },
       ScanIndexForward: false, // false for descending order
       Limit: 10 // Limit response to 10 items
    }
```

Alternatively, you can perform changes to your primary key by [making it a unique combination of `date` and `score`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html), to be able to effectively query across multiple parameters.